# how do you allocate memory for a buffer in iOS

Tags: ios, memory, audio, memory-management, buffer

I have an AudioQueueBufferRef datatype and I want to allocate memory for the buffers but I don't want to associate it with the queue. Hence, I can't use AudioQueueAllocateBufferWithPacketDescription.
What is the general way of allocating memory to any buffer?

I tried malloc but it didn't work

```
        for(i=0;i<numBuffers;i++){
          AudBuf[i] = (AudioQueueBufferRef)malloc(sizeof(AudioQueueBuffer));
```

}

Comment: I tried malloc but it didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it didn't work'? What error do you get, and at what step (compilation, runtime, etc.) ?

Comment: Plus, `AudioQueueBuffer` is a data structure which holds a pointer to the beginning of the data, so using `sizeof` is not the correct way to alloc the buffer.

Comment: But isn't that how you find out te sizeof a struct. I think what you're saying is AudioQueueBufferRef which is a pointer to AudioQueueBuffer. So how do I allocate memory for the buffer? Not working, as in , I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I'm guessing because the memory hasn't been allocated.

Comment: `malloc` gets as an input the number of bytes you want to alloc. If you want a pointer `int *ip` to point to an array of 1000 integers, you have to alloc `1000*sizeof(int)` bytes. That's different from `sizeof(ip)`, which will give you the size of the "pointer to int" data type. You have to know the data type of your samples, and the length of the buffer, and then allocate `numOfSamples * sizeof(sampleDataType)` bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [AudioFileStreamExample](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/AudioFileStreamExample/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008648-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) from apple.

Answer (score 0):

```
AudioQueueBuffer dummyAQB;
audioQueueBuffer = malloc(sizeof(dummyAQB)*kNumAQBufs);
```